# can't find a way to make this triangle pattern

Tags: python

I'm trying this question where i need to make this triangle pattern only using the codes given below:

```
*
***
*****
*******
*********
```

[image: the blanks should be filled with the codes below]

These are the codes that are allowed to be used:

```
count += 1
star = "*"
continue
count = 10
elif:
print (star,end="")
print()
print (star)
break 
i % 2 == 0
i % 2 == 1
```

This i what i managed to make and I can't seem to find a way to get the above output with the codes given:

```
count=10
star="*"
for i in range (count):
    if i%2==0:
        print(star)
    else:
        for x in range (i):
            print(star,end="*")
        count+=1
```

Comment: Why do you use `count+=1` where you do?

Comment: To skip even # lines, use `continue`. Compare your code to print a single star to the teacher's. Don't forget to print a newline.

Comment: `count+=1` has no effect. The value of `count` is only used at the beginning of the loop to determine when to stop.

Comment: `print(start, end="*")` will print two stars. Since it's inside the loop, you'll get `2*i` stars.

Comment: `break` and `i % 2 == 0` should not be in the same item in the list of allowed codes.

Comment: @Barmar correct, i accidentally posted them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, first things first : you got your definition correctly in your first lines :

```py
count=10
star="*"
for i in range(count):
```

If you look closely at the pattern, you can notice if you look closely at the pattern that every line is made of an odd number of stars : 1,3,5... so bascially, you want to "skip" every iteration with an even number of stars, and that's what `continue` is for, to bring you to the next iteration loop.
Keep in mind tho that Python `range` iteration starts at 0, so every line contains one more star than its index. To sum up, **you want to print even lines (with an odd number of stars) and skip odd lines (with an even number of stars)** :

```py
if (i%2 == 1):      # if you're looking at an odd line (with an even number of stars)
    continue        # skip this iteration
else:               # we're now sure we're on an even line
```

Now we have our even lines only. For each of these lines, we want to keep as many stars as the line index (the `i` index) + 1. When using the `print` method, the default value for `end` is `\n`, the character for a newline, so when you use `print` by default it prints a line and goes to the next line. The `print(star, end="")` instruction will help us by forcing the code to stay on the same line and not going to a new line. Remember how we said we wanted to print (i+1) stars ? **Then we can print i starts, and for the i+1st one, we can go to a new line**.

```py
for x in range(i):
            print(star,end="")    #print our star and prevents the new line
        print(star)               #once we printed our i stars, we print the i+1 and go to a new line
```

To sum up :

```py
count=10
star="*"
for i in range (count):
    if (i%2 == 1):      # if you're looking at an odd line (with an even number of stars)
        continue        # skip this iteration
    else:               # we're now sure we're on an even line
        for x in range(i):
            print(star,end="")    # print our star and stay on the same line
        print(star)               # once we printed our i stars, we print the i+1 and go to a new line
```

Answer (score 0):

this algorithm go from 0 to 10, if the number is even it will continue if the number is odd it will print the stars as much as the i variable is currently in.

```
count = 10
star = '*'
for i in range(count):
    if(i%2 == 0):
        continue
    else:
        for x in range(i):
            print(star, end="")
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired pattern using the given code

```
count=10
star = '*'
for i in range(count):
  if i%2 == 0:
    print(star * (i+1))
  else:
    for x in range(i):
      print(star, end='')
    print(star)
```